# How cmake handle include_directories() for a project with nested folder

Tags: c++, cmake

The problem is **solved**, it is due to other dependency of my project, it has nothing wrong with cmake. Thanks for everyone trying to help in the question.

Here is my project tree `Tree 1`:

```
project 
| + src
| | + other_src
| | | - abc.cpp
| | | - abc.h
| | - main.cpp
| - CMakeLists.txt
3rd_party
| + pcap
| | - pcap.h
| - pcap.h
```

Inside my CMakeLists.txt, I do:

```
include_directories("/path/to/3rd_party")
```

Inside my `abc.cpp`, I have:

```
#include "pcap.h"
```

Then I do `cmake` and `make`. I get error `pcap.h: No such file or directory`

I then change my project tree `Tree 2`:

```
project 
| + src
| | - abc.cpp
| | - abc.h
| | - main.cpp
| - CMakeLists.txt
3rd_party
| + pcap
| | - pcap.h
| - pcap.h
```

Without modifying my `CMakeLists.txt`, I do `cmake` and `make` again. The header file is found.

How can I build this project while my source code is placed in different folders?

Comment: Hi @Oliv, I have tried to put those `3rd_party header files` inside my project but the error still exist.

Comment: Command `include_directories` affects on nested directories. It looks like the problem is somewhere else. Show the rest of code (CMake) and **precise error message**.

Comment: within include_directories("/path/to/3rd_party") : are you using relative or absolute path ?

Comment: @StPiere you mean in the source code? For example `#include "pcap.h"` I am using relative path. In `CMakeLists.txt`, I am using absolute path.

Comment: no, I mean within cmake: is "/path/to/3rd_party" absolute or relative path ?

Comment: Shouldn't the path to your library be "/path/to/3rd_party/pcap"? In your include command you are suggesting that it can be found in one of the include directories, not a subfolder of it.

Comment: Why option 2 is working but all the others are not is not obvious to me, maybe you accidentally changed more than you suggest. Can you make a minimal **working** example?

Comment: `Why option 2 is working`, yes this is the question I want to know. The full version of my project is here: https://github.com/SulfredLee/PcapReplayer.
Hopefully, you can see or repeat my problem. `PcapReplayer/BackEnd/CMakeLists.txt`, this is the `CMakeLists.txt` file with the nested folder structure. `PcapReplayer/BackEnd/PlayerEngine/AdapterInfo.h` this is the file including `pcap.h`

Comment: You can easily test and run what you post here right? I would be relevant to do just that to zoom in to the problem.